# GitHub Actions: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: overflow reading version string

Tags: laravel, ssh, continuous-integration, github-actions, linode

I have DO server and a Linode server and am connecting both of them to a GitHub Actions pipeline.  I am testing out my ssh connection after reading the json config file and the DO server seems to work ok but the Linode doesn't and get the above error, does anyone know what the cause is?  My private ssh key and public keys have both been added. My deploy-application.yaml file is below. Thank you for any help!

```
name: Deploy Application
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  laravel-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Use Node.js 12.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12.x

      - name: Install composer dependencies
        run: composer install --prefer-dist

      - name: Install npm dependencies
        run: npm install

      - name: Run Mix
        run: npm run production

      - name: Prepare Laravel Application
        run: |
          cp .env.example .env
          php artisan key:generate

      - name: Run PHPUnit
        run: php8.0 vendor/bin/phpunit

  create-deployment-artifacts:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [laravel-tests]
    outputs:
      deployment-matrix: ${{ steps.export-deployment-matrix.outputs.deployment-matrix }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Compile CSS and Javascript
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run prod

      - name: Setup PHP with PECL extension
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: "8.0"
          extensions: mbstring, ctype, fileinfo, openssl, PDO, bcmath, json, tokenizer, xml, imagick, swoole, ext-dom, ext-curl

      - name: Composer install
        run: composer install -q --no-ansi --no-dev --no-interaction --no-scripts --no-progress --prefer-dist

      - name: Create deployment artifact
        env:
          GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
        run: tar -czf "${GITHUB_SHA}".tar.gz --exclude=*.git --exclude=node_modules *

      - name: Store artifact for distribution
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: app-build
          path: ${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz

      - name: Export deployment matrix
        id: export-deployment-matrix
        run: |
          JSON="$(cat ./deployment-config.json)"
          JSON="${JSON//'%'/'%25'}"
          JSON="${JSON//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
          JSON="${JSON//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
          echo "::set-output name=deployment-matrix::$JSON"

  testing-ssh-connection:
    name: testing ssh connection
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [laravel-tests, create-deployment-artifacts]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - name: Testing ssh connection
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          script: |
            echo this works

  prepare-release-on-servers:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: Prepare release"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [laravel-tests, create-deployment-artifacts, 
    testing-ssh-connection
    ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: app-build
      - name: Upload
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          source: ${{ github.sha }}.tar.gz
          target: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/artifacts
      - name: Extract archive and create directories
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          envs: GITHUB_SHA
          script: |
            pwd
            mkdir -p "${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${GITHUB_SHA}"
            chmod -R 0777 "${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${GITHUB_SHA}"
            tar xzf ${{ matrix.server.path }}/artifacts/${GITHUB_SHA}.tar.gz -C "${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${GITHUB_SHA}"
            rm -rf ${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${GITHUB_SHA}/storage

            mkdir -p ${{ matrix.server.path }}/storage/{app,public,framework,logs}
            mkdir -p ${{ matrix.server.path }}/storage/framework/{cache,sessions,testing,views}
            chmod -R 0777 ${{ matrix.server.path }}/storage

  run-before-hooks:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: Before hook"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      [
        laravel-tests,
        create-deployment-artifacts,
        testing-ssh-connection,
        prepare-release-on-servers,
      ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - name: Run before hooks
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
          RELEASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${{ github.sha }}
          ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/current
          STORAGE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/storage
          BASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          envs: GITHUB_SHA,RELEASE_PATH,ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH,STORAGE_PATH,BASE_PATH
          script: |
            ${{ matrix.server.beforeHooks }}

  activate-release:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: Activate release"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      [
        laravel-tests,
        create-deployment-artifacts,
        testing-ssh-connection,
        prepare-release-on-servers,
        run-before-hooks,
      ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - name: Activate release
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
          RELEASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${{ github.sha }}
          ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/current
          STORAGE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/storage
          BASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}
          LARAVEL_ENV: ${{ secrets.LARAVEL_ENV }}
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          envs: GITHUB_SHA,RELEASE_PATH,ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH,STORAGE_PATH,BASE_PATH,ENV_PATH,LARAVEL_ENV
          script: |
            printf "%s" "$LARAVEL_ENV" > "${BASE_PATH}/.env"
            ln -s -f ${BASE_PATH}/.env $RELEASE_PATH
            ln -s -f $STORAGE_PATH $RELEASE_PATH
            ln -s -n -f $RELEASE_PATH $ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH

  run-after-hooks:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: After hook"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      [
        laravel-tests,
        create-deployment-artifacts,
        testing-ssh-connection,
        prepare-release-on-servers,
        run-before-hooks,
        activate-release,
      ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - name: Run after hooks
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_SHA: ${{ github.sha }}
          RELEASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases/${{ github.sha }}
          ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/current
          STORAGE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/storage
          BASE_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          envs: GITHUB_SHA,RELEASE_PATH,ACTIVE_RELEASE_PATH,STORAGE_PATH,BASE_PATH
          script: |
            ${{ matrix.server.afterHooks }}
            pwd

  clean-up:
    name: "${{ matrix.server.name }}: Clean up"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs:
      [
        laravel-tests,
        create-deployment-artifacts,
        testing-ssh-connection,
        prepare-release-on-servers,
        run-before-hooks,
        activate-release,
        run-after-hooks,
      ]
    strategy:
      matrix:
        server: ${{ fromJson(needs.create-deployment-artifacts.outputs.deployment-matrix) }}
    steps:
      - name: Run after hooks
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        env:
          RELEASES_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/releases
          ARTIFACTS_PATH: ${{ matrix.server.path }}/artifacts
        with:
          host: ${{ matrix.server.ip }}
          username: ${{ matrix.server.username }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ matrix.server.port }}
          envs: RELEASES_PATH
          script: |
            cd $RELEASES_PATH && ls -t -1 | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf
            cd $ARTIFACTS_PATH && ls -t -1 | tail -n +6 | xargs rm -rf
```